# stop asynctask. How turn off or stop background process of another execution?

Tags: android, background, android-asynctask

I am creating an APK but I have a problem.
My APK sends a GET request when it finishes.
I have a `asynctask` class for sending a GET request periodically.
The problem is that when I start the application again I need to kill the background processes of the previous launch.
I put `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"` and `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"` in the manifest.xml, and used the following code:

```
if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(URL_Pet_GET) && URLUtil.isValidUrl(URL_Host)){
    //Get_Backgnd.cancel(true); not working  
      context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
      manager.killBackgroundProcesses(String.valueOf(process.processName));
    //not working

    //ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService("activity");
    //activityManager.restartPackage(packageName);
    //not working

    pet_get_backgrnd Get_Backgnd = new pet_get_backgrnd();
    Get_Backgnd.execute();  //Send GET request that I need stop on next execution of apk 
}  
private class pet_get_backgrnd extends AsyncTask<Context, Object, Object>{
    /*@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        cancel(true);
    }*/ //not working
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Context... params) { 
        //send Get requests
    }
}
```

How can I cancel the execution of `Get_Backgnd` on the next execution of the APK?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that when I start the application again need to kill the processes of the background previous launch.

There is no "processes of the background previous launch", unless you did something rather unusual in your manifest. Most Android apps have just one process, and so if your `AsyncTask` is doing something, it is doing that in your current process.

> How I cancel the execution of Get_Backgnd on next apk execution?

Call `cancel()` on the `AsyncTask` object. If it is running, the object exists, so call `cancel()` on it.

Of course, it is also possible that the right answer is to rewrite your app to "send Get request periodically"  using something else that does not involve an `AsyncTask` (e.g., `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService`).

Comment: This solution don't solve the problem.   If I put cancel() on it, I can't start new asyncTask.  The apk not send new GET requests.